# Is it true that $\mathbb R \setminus \bigcup A\not= \emptyset$?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be the set of all nonempty compact nowhere dense subsets of the real line. Given any countable subset $A$ of $X$. Is it true that $\mathbb R \setminus \bigcup A\not= \emptyset$?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes: that’s just (a special case of) the [Baire category theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem). A compact, nowhere dense subset of $\Bbb R$ is a closed nowhere dense set, so in fact $\Bbb R\setminus\bigcup A$ is even dense in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @Paul: You’re welcome!